# field type URL. how to prepare csv for this?

Tags: powershell, import, url, splist

I am running a powershell to import csv into a list. There is one field "ProviderURL" in the list. In the csv I had http://www.contoso.com and it imported fine. Howerver, I would like it to be Contoso as Description and http://www.contoso.com as a link.

How would I format my csv so that powershell will add providerURL in this fashion?

btw, here is the ps script

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb http://portal.company.com/site1
$spList = $spWeb.lists["TestList"]
$csvFile = "c:\\import.csv"
foreach($item in Import-CSV $csvFile)
{
    $newItem = $spList.Items.Add()
    $newItem["Title"] = $item.Title
    $newItem["ProviderURL"] = $item.ProviderURL
    $newItem.Update()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to approach your issue.

1. Make sure your csv have an additional column for url description. Let's call that "urlDescription"
2. Now add following to your PS script.

   $field = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldURLValue

   $field.Description = $item.urlDescription

   $field.URL = $item.ProviderURL

   $newItem["ProviderURL"] = $field

I hope this helps.

Comment: It worked like charm. THIS IS FIRST TIME I GOT A QUICK RESPOND. I FEEL LIKE THIS SITE IS DEAD AS I HARDLY GET ANY REPLY. THANKS Monica for your help.